# Command runs in terminal but not from .sh file

Tags: android, windows, bash, sh, adb

I have made a script that I want to run on an Android phone through Android Studio on a Windows computer. I try to run the .sh file in the "Androdi\Skd\platform-tools" folder and specifying the bash script since I am using windows like this:
`"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" test.sh`

The file only consists this line:

```
adb shell am start -n "com.example.testaware/com.example.testaware.activities.MainActivity" -a androids.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

When doing this, nothing happens.

But when I do this outside of the script directly in the terminal, the app starts.

```
C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>    adb shell am start -n "com.example.testaware/com.example.testaware.activities.MainActivity" -a androids.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER

Starting: Intent { act=androids.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.testaware/.activities.MainActivity }
```

Does anyone know what the problem can be and why the app does not start when trying it through a script?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `platform-tools` folder in PATH.

1. Go to Control panel > System > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables
2. Select Path and add `C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`

Comment: Thanks this works! I don't get the error, but it still seems like nothing happens and the app I am trying to start with the command does not start.